# Android SimpleDateFormat problem

Tags: java, android, date-format, simpledateformat

```
SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
Date date = (Date)formatter.parse("2011-09-13");
Log.e(MY_DEBUG_TAG, "Output is "+ date.getYear() + " /" + date.getMonth() + " / "+ (date.getDay()+1));
```

Is out putting

`09-13 14:20:18.740: ERROR/GoldFishActivity(357): Output is 111 /8 / 3`

What is the issue?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The methods you are using in the `Date` class are deprecated.

- You get 111 for the year, because `getYear()` returns a value that is the result of subtracting 1900 from the year i.e. `2011 - 1900 = 111`.
- You get 3 for the day, because `getDay()` returns the day of the week and `3 = Wednesday`. `getDate()` returns the day of the month, but this too is deprecated.

You should use the `Calendar` class instead.

```
SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
Date date = (Date)formatter.parse("2011-09-13");        
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();  
cal.setTime(date);
Log.e(MY_DEBUG_TAG, "Output is "+ cal.get(Calendar.YEAR)+ " /" + (cal.get(Calendar.MONTH)+1) + " / "+ cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH));
```

Comment: Why does `getYear()` return `year - 1900`? Why doesn't it only return the year?

Answer (score 4):

Read the [javadoc of `java.util.Date`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Date.html) carefully.

`getYear` returns the number of years since 1900.

`getMonth` returns the month, starting from 0 (0 = January, 1 = February, etc.).

`getDay` returns the day of week (0 = Sunday, 1 = Monday, etc.), not the day of month.

And all these methods are deprecated. You shouldn't use them anymore.